# bash copying log files into separate directories

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not an expert bash, but I try solve that problem:

1. I have lots of files `*.log`, which I don't know creation date,
2. I need copy them to separated directories called `$date_when_was_file_created` eg. files created `2017-01-12` have to be moved to directory called `2017-01-12`

files created `2017-02-12` have to be moved to directory called `2017-02-12`

So what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
dirs=`ls -la -F --full-time *.LOG | awk '{print $6}'`
filedate=`ls -la -F --full-time *.LOG | awk '{print $6}'>dat`

mkdir $dirs

for data in `cat dat`
        do echo " ther are file to be copied:--> `ls -la -F --full-time *.LOG | awk '{print $6 " " $9}' | grep $data  | awk '{print $2}'` "
                if [[ $data == $dirs ]];
                        then cp `ls -la -F --full-time *.LOG | awk '{print $6 " " $9}' | grep $data  | awk '{print $2}'` $dirs
                fi
        done
```

But it doesn't work, mean creates directories, but don't copy files, why? I don't know... Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both POSIX shell and bash provide *parameter expansions* to trim portions of a string. The `stat` utility can provide the full create time (including hours, minutes, seconds...). Simply use the `stat` function and trim the time from the string create time returned by `stat` leaving the date. Then just create a directory using the date and move your log file into it. E.g.

```
for file in *.log                   ## loop over log files
do
    ctime=$(stat -c%y "$file")      ## get full create time
    cdate="${ctime%% *}"            ## extract YYYY-MM-DD date
    mkdir -p "$cdate"               ## create dir if it doesn't exist
    mv "$file" "$cdate"             ## move log to directory
done
```

Look it over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Bash is an amazing shell that can pretty much do anything you need related to Linux system administration. Well worth the time spent to learn it, and the difference between bash and POSIX shell (e.g. ash, dash -- and the old bourne shell)